# Can you include a Svelte Component in a ReactJS project?

Tags: reactjs, svelte

I have just started to study Svelte. Just curious to know if you can import a Svelte component into a React project. A small hello-world example would suffice.

Comment: https://github.com/Rich-Harris/react-svelte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like React can be used as smooth inculcation. And that is why, you can include one react component on existing page.

What about svelte? Maybe you are searching this:
https://svelte.dev/docs#Component_format

```js
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
 target: document.querySelector('#server-rendered-html'),
 hydrate: true
});
```